# .htaccess Adding Duplicate URL

Tags: .htaccess, ipb

So the issue I am having is with .htaccess duplicating a portion of the url. Essentially, I have an IPB installed in **root/forum/** and the .htaccess (code shown below) duplicates forum so that the url looks like **root/forum/forum/**

Here is the .htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forum/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Removing **/forum** from the .htaccess breaks the site. Is it my .htaccess code or is this something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my .htaccess, that is equal to your ...

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /forum/public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And is all working fine here. i have a forum inside "forum" folder too...
Do you have activated the .htaccess mod_rewrite setting in adminCP ??

You acess your forum by this url (http://site.com/forum) or this (http://forum.site.com)? i use the first one, and work nice here...